# d3.js transition of donuts created by multi-arcs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created a donut using multi-arcs and I want to update my donut with new data(arcs).

```
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var p = Math.PI * 2;

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                              .attr("width", width)
                              .attr("height", height);

var group = vis.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var arcs = [];

arcs[0] = d3.svg.arc()
                   .innerRadius(50)
                   .outerRadius(70)
                   .startAngle(0)
                   .endAngle(p - 2);

arcs[1] = d3.svg.arc()
                  .innerRadius(50)
                  .outerRadius(70)
                  .startAngle(p - 2)
                  .endAngle(p);

group.append("path")
               .attr("d", arcs[0])
               .attr("class", "first")
               .attr("fill", "green");

group.append("path")
               .attr("d", arcs[1])
               .attr("class", "second")
               .attr("fill", "grey");
```

The new data(arcs - functions) must be in arrays and I have to pass them using the .data(dataset) method.

```
// New data
var data1 = [];
data1[0] = d3.svg.arc()
                   .innerRadius(60)
                   .outerRadius(100)
                   .startAngle(0)
                   .endAngle(p - 1);

var data2 = [];
data2[0] = d3.svg.arc()
                   .innerRadius(60)
                   .outerRadius(100)
                   .startAngle(p - 1) 
                   .endAngle(p);
```

-I can update my donut with the new arcs but the issue that I have is that the transition doesn't work.

-I want just to make the transition work following the steps that I described before.
I know already that if i don't use the .data(dataset) method and I use the .attr("d", arc) instead of .attrTween method then the transition will work.

-However that is not what I want because I want to apply the solution to multi-donuts.

```
//On click, update with new data      
d3.select("p")
      .on("click", function () {

//Update all rects
vis.selectAll("path.first")
        .data(data1)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) { return d; });

vis.selectAll("path.second")
        .data(data2)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) { return d; });
```

Here is an example, click update to see the changes: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dragomirlam/TmQL7/)

Comment: You need a custom tween function for arcs, see e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

Comment: And I'd advise looking carefully at the rest of the code, your example code is very confusingly written and does not take advantage of d3's data-driven approach.  Check out [the tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials).

Comment: Thanks a lot both for your comments and your advices! It was a bit hard to understand how the tween function works but I managed to make the transition. When I will fix the other issues that I have I will post here the results!